# How to solve FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, anaconda3, virtual-environment

I'm trying to launch a github repository https://github.com/grei-ufc/market-simulation.git, the cloning works fine but when i got to launch the simulation I receive a Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launcher.py", line 7, in <module>
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\serge\anaconda3\envs\example_market\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\serge\anaconda3\envs\example_market\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The launcher.py reads

```
import subprocess
import shlex
from time import sleep

commands = 'pade start_runtime --config_file pade_config.json'
commands = shlex.split(commands)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

sleep(15.0)

commands = 'python start_mosaik_sim.py'
commands = shlex.split(commands)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

sleep(60.0)

p1.terminate()
p2.terminate()
```

pade command comes from a .json file

```
{   
"agent_files": [
     "start_pade_agents.py"
],
"port": 1234,
"num": 1,
"pade_ams": {
    "launch": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8000
},
"pade_web": {
    "active": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5000
},
"pade_sniffer": {
    "active": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8001
},
"session": {
    "username": "pade_user",
    "email": "pade_user@pade.com",
    "password": "12345"    
}
```

}

How can I go about solving this? Thank you

I've tried changing the pathway of a created environment to the github repository but that didn't work

Comment: If `commands` is a list, its first element needs to be the name of a valid executable. The error message implies that it doesn't. Since you aren't showing us what `commands` contains, or how you determined the name to be one that corresponds to a valid executable, I don't know how we can answer this as-given.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand sorry the commnad is not a list but reads

commands = 'pade start_runtime --config_file pade_config.json'
// commands = shlex.split(commands)
 // p1 = subprocess.Popen(commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: [Edit] the question to add missing information please.

Comment: That said, `shlex.split` turns what you have into a list., so it's a list before you try to run it. Where does the `pade` command come from?

Comment: Oh okay really appreciate this thanks for your patience, I'm getting up the pade file

Comment: I've edited my question to show the .json file that the pade command comes from

Comment: JSON files don't typically define commands (an operating system typically finds commands by looking for executable files in the directories named in PATH; on Windows, that would mean looking for a `pade.bat`, a `pade.exe`, or similar)

Comment: I've figured out what's wrong the original pade files have been updated and aren't compatible with the simulation, I've found a set of instructions on the github and am going to try updating hopefully should work. But thank you so much for the help so far if it persists I will look to update this page!! Really appreciate the support